# My button onclick attribute is not working in ejs templating

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I created a toggle button that switches between light and dark mode. It works fine when I render it as a static file but doesn’t work when I render it dynamically with ejs templating.
Please can anyone help me out by pointing to what is causing the bug in my code.

Here is my index.ejs file:

```
<body>
<button type=“submit” onclick= <%“darkMode()”%> class=“myBtn”>
<span class=“moon-icon”></span> 
<span class=“sun-icon”>☀️</span> 
</button>


<%function darkMode(){%>
 <%document.body.classList.toggle('dark');%>
<%}%>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried putting the darkMode() function inside a script tag in the ejs file like this:

```
<script> 

function darkMode(){
 document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}

</script>
```

But it still didn’t work.

My app.js file:

```
app.get(“/“, function(req, res){
res.render(“index”);
});
```

My css file

```
button{
background-color:green;
}
.dark button{
background-color: yellow;
}

.dark .moon-icon, .sun-icon{
Display: none;
}
 
.dark .sun-icon{
Display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem lies in the unicode quotation characters you are using. I can only assume you copied from a website or word doc possibly and your IDE/text editor hasn't picked it up and it's all over your code. For example, in this line:

```
<span class=“moon-icon”></span>
```

The quotation marks you are using to surround the word `moon-icon` are [Unicode Character (U+201C)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201C) and [Unicode Character (U+201D)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201D). These are wrong. What you need to use is [Unicode Character(U+0022)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0022). They need to look like this:

```
<span class="moon-icon"></span>
```

HTML can be very forgiving in that it will still output your `span` elements but your `css-selectors` are not being applied as the browser can't find them properly.

In addition I would refrain from using `onclick` if it's not required by a framework. Try giving the button an id and then use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to listen for the clicks. Something like this in your ejs file:

```
<body>
   <button id="toggle-dark" type="submit">
      <span class="moon-icon"></span> 
      <span class="sun-icon">☀️</span> 
   </button>
</body>
```

In your JavaScript file:

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('#toggle-dark');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', (evt) =>{
   evt.preventDefault();
   document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
```